# Php Shopping Cart Add button isn't working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have here a sample of shopping cart using php. I tried to modify it to what I need. What I add here is a search function using ajax/jquery. The search engine working but the problem is the add button isn't working. Why I can't add a item in the list? What I does here is separate the table in index.php into search.php so when I try to search only the item what I need is going to display in table. Any help will appreciate.

**Search.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");
    //current URL of the Page. cart_update.php redirects back to this URL
$current_url = base64_encode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if(isset($_POST['bid'])) {
$search = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['bid']);
$search = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $search);
$search = $_POST['bid'];

    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from app WHERE item_name LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY item_name ASC");
        echo'<table id="tfhover" cellspacing="0" class="table-list" style="text-transform:uppercase;" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
        <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>';
        echo'<tbody>';
if(($results->num_rows)>= 1){
        while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
        {
            echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">';
            echo '<tr>
                    <td style="text-align:left;">'.$obj->item_name.'</td>
                    <td><button class="add_to_cart" style="font-size:9px;">Add</button></td>
                </tr>';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="'.$obj->counter.'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />';
            echo '</form>';
        }
    echo "</tbody></table>";
    }
if(($results->num_rows)<= 0){
echo '<div style="margin-left:360px;">No Results</div>';
}
}
?>
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");
    //current URL of the Page. cart_update.php redirects back to this URL
$current_url = base64_encode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>
    <input type="text" name="bid" id="bid" placeholder="Search" style="text-transform:uppercase;width:300px;text-align:center;"/>
<div id="bid_result"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    function load(query) {
        $.post('search.php', {
            bid: query
        }, function (search_bid) {
            $('#bid_result').stop(true, true).fadeIn(200).html(search_bid);
        }); //End ajax call
    }

    load($("#bid").val());
    //Live search
    $("#bid").on('keyup', function () {
        //Input field value
        load($(this).val());
    }); //End on function
}); //End document.ready state
</script>
```

**Cart_update.php**

Here's my complete code of cart_update.php http://pastebin.com/1iDENLa0

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");
if(isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"]=='add')
{
$product_code   = filter_var($_POST["product_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); // product code
$return_url     = base64_decode($_POST["return_url"]); //return url
}
?>
```

Comment: @vlzvl I didn't inlclude that. Bcoz I think that's not the problem. The Add button are not firing.

Comment: @vlzvl This was the complete code of cart_update.php http://pastebin.com/1iDENLa0

Comment: I'm not sure what be the problem but i see that you're adding a form inside a `table` but _not_ into a cell. Consider putting the form inside a `<td>` (etc. `<tbody><td>...</td></tbody>`)

Comment: @vlzvl I already did that. But the problem if you put the form out the while loop only the first item in the table will always add. That exactly I used and it's working before I try to add search engine.

Comment: @vlzvl I'm thinking if it because ajax sends the table into div_result. So that add button didn't recognize or form action not firing? I'm a bit of desperate about this problem. Help please

Comment: No, i didn't said outside the while loop, just add a `<tbody><td>` since you're actually rendering something (form) into nowhere. Table contents must be inside cells and your form is a table content. Just replace with this `echo'<tbody><td>';` and close the cell in the end.

Comment: @vlzvl I did what you said but also isn't working.

Comment: @vlzvl It is bcoz of ajax. When I try to add form in index.php between div_result the add button fire but the problem just like what I said the last item of list always add. And the window goes into search.php.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i changed some parts of your code, can you check this code? It should submit.

```
<?php
    echo '
    <table id="tfhover" cellspacing="0" class="table-list" style="text-transform:uppercase;" border="1">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th></th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>';
    if(($results->num_rows)>= 1) {
       while($obj = $results->fetch_object()) {
          echo '
                <form method="post" action="cart_update.php">
                 <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="'.$obj->counter.'" />
                 <input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />
                 <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />
                 <input type="submit" class="add_to_cart" value="Add" style="font-size:9px;"/>
                </form>';
       }
       echo '</tr></td>';
    }
    echo "</tbody></table>";
?>
```

Comment: (im trying to emulate it a bit myself)

Comment: Okay. But I think it bcoz of ajax :/

Comment: The ajax works well and is bringing back the form(s) once it get called. The `keyup` also works good, loading the new search add buttons each time you type letters. Just something to think, does your jquery version (what is) can really use the `on` ? i had to replace it with `live` since i have an older version. Other than that, i need to understand better the problem now i have the code to my pc.